# How to call perl from csh and have it include custom libraries?

Tags: perl, csh

I have a csh script, from which I am calling a perl script.

```
set xyz = `perl my_perl.pl`;
```

Here is something from my_perl.pl

```
#usr/bin/perl
BEGIN {
 @INC = ('/path/to/my/lib/folder', @INC);
}
use my_lib;

sub test {
my_lib::foo();
}
```

So, when I run my csh like this

```
./run
```

It says `Can't locate my_lib.pm in @INC`

If I run my_perl separately like `perl -e my_perl.pl` it works fine.

How can i make this work from my csh as well? I did some checks here and it seems that it is not executing BEGIN block. If I put a `print "test";` in BEGIN, it doesnt work.

Please help on this.

(Note: I have to use csh, so please don't suggest me not to use csh)

Comment: `perl -e my_perl.pl` does **not** execute the script in `my_perl.pl`.  It executes the string `my_perl.pl` as Perl code (i.e., 2 barewords and the string concatenation operator).

Comment: Tried without -e, still facing the same problem

Comment: have you tried printing @INC before you call use my_lib, that will let you see what its defined as.

Comment: Your shebang line misses a bang.

Comment: @choroba I thought the same but guessing the user typed this as an example rather than his actual code. Since if it wasnt running under perl it wouldnt know about \@INC etc so i guess this is not the actual code.

Comment: Yes. this is not actual code ! @INC doesn't seem to get the path that I am trying to include - and that's what bothers me to post this question !

Comment: what if you simplyfy the problem. From csh can you call a perl script that simply contains `print "testin1\n";
BEGIN {print "testing2\n";}
print "testing3\n";` this should print in the order of 2, 1, 3. That will at least let you know the begin is working.

Comment: If you don't post the actual code, how can we find out what causes the problem?

Comment: I tried it and not seeing any issues. When you are running perl script separately, make sure you are in a directory which doesnt have the module.

Comment: Try using `use lib '/path/to/my/lib/folder';` instead of `BEGIN { ... }` -- Those should be equivalent, but `use lib` is the more-recommended way.

Answer (score 0):

As suggested by @Dre, i added 
`use lib 'blah blah';` and it seems to be working. (Though i still do not know what is wrong with the way i was doing it)

Thank you for suggestions everyone.

Answer (score -1):

Did you try to include your custom libraries to PERL5LIB env?

Delete BEGIN block from your code and try:

```
setenv PERL5LIB "/path/to/my/lib/folder"
./my_perl.pl
```

Comment: That is *sh* syntax, not *csh* syntax.